# Usage of exit()

Tags: c++, error-handling

I've found this code and I don't understand why they end the program with **exit(0)** when the input is not valid. Why they didn't use **exit(1)**? I've heard that we should use exit(1) when there is a failure. So when I should use EXIT_FAILURE or EXIT_SUCCESS?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"Enter a non-zero value: ";  //user input
    cin>>i;
    if(i)    // checks whether the user input is non-zero or not
    {
        cout<<"Valid input.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"ERROR!";  //the program exists if the value is 0
        exit(0);
    }
    cout<<"The input was : "<<i;
}
```

Comment: It's a legitimate question, C89 precises that both `EXIT_SUCCESS`  and the value zero indicate successful program execution status. Thus we're not forced to use 0 as a success exit status, but there's strong reasons to do so : 1) Readability with `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE` 2) Many build chains / tool chains expect that programs/commands return 0 for success and non zero otherwise. 3) As far as i know, all the OS expect 0 for success.

Comment: 99.9999% or more of the time the exit code from a program is ignored. Yes, it's sloppy, but in practice it just doesn't matter what the return code is.

Comment: There is no `return` for default `main` finish and you ask why `exit` returns zero. Because the author of this does not know the meaning of exit codes, etc. BTW, in this case `exit` can be simple `return -1;`. `exit` is necessary if program is terminated in nested function.

Comment: Appears that the person who wrote the code did not consider `ERROR!` input to be a failure condition to be returned to the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for them to use exit(0) in that situation. Maybe they just wanted the program to exit gracefully despite the incorrect input. Don't waste time trying to understand their thinking behind that decision. You can use either whenever you feel it fits.